# Response not reflecting changes

Tags: node.js, express, get, request, response

I am experiencing some really weird behavior.The app was working fine  and then even when i change the room id nothing changes in response .
i even tried to remove **app.get()** method and call that route **/api/availability**, the response still pops up

```
app.get("/api/availability", (req, res) => {
        res.json({ availability : availableroomsArray});});
```

No matter what I call , I get the same old response , changing the route to **/api/available** instead of **/api/availability** will show the same response in **/api/availability**.

this is my code :

```
    var availableroomsArray = [];
    var arrayAll = [];
    var rooms =[];
    var roomIds=[9748,7264,59038,110158,42714]
    var obj = {};
    const start = async function() {
        // GET THE ROOMS
    const body = {propId: "3578",
      roomId: true};
    const response =await fetch('https://api.beds24.com/json/getDescriptions', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
    const data = await response.json();
            for (let i in roomIds) {
            arrayAll.push(data["properties"]["rooms"][roomIds[i]]);
            app.get("/api/rooms", (req, res) => {
            res.json({ rooms: arrayAll});});
            }
    
    
        var from=await dateFormat(Date.now(), "yyyymmdd");
            console.log("aa"+from);
        var to=await dateFormat(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)), "yyyymmdd");
        console.log("aa"+to);
    
    
    
    //GET ROOM'S AVAILABILITY
        for (let i in roomIds) {
    const AvailBody = {"authentication": {
            "apiKey": "privatekey",
            "propKey": "privatekey"
        },
        "from": from, // datenow w format
        "to": to,
        "roomId": roomIds[i]
    };
    const AvailResponse =await fetch('https://api.beds24.com/json/getRoomDates', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(AvailBody),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
    var indicateur = roomIds[i] 
    const Availabilitydata = await AvailResponse.json();
            obj[roomIds[i]] = Availabilitydata;
    
    
        }
        availableroomsArray.push(obj);
    
    
        app.post("/api/availability", (req, res) => {
            res.json({ availability : availableroomsArray});});
    
    
    }
```

Comment: I find this code very difficult to reason about, from the random formatting to what’s intended. What’s supposed to change, and why?

Comment: I don't think the problem remains with the code , the code was running fine ( in the request ) i do send date.now , so every day the request get sent again with the new value of the date . today the app crushed and when i restarted it , i noticed nothing is changing in the response when i change the date / or the response itself .

Comment: There’s nothing in any request handler that does anything depending on anything in the request. They all return data determined by the processing that happens when `start()` is called, including the route to `/rooms`, which is defined over and over in a loop.

Comment: Normally a request handler would use data in the request to determine what data to return, e.g., a room ID would be used to return just that room’s data. If there’s an external request required to get that data it would be run *at the time of the request* in order to get current data rather than data retrieved at app startup. Routes are not generally redefined over an app’s lifetime, rather once, at startup.

Comment: I know , You misunderstood what i am trying to say . to simplify it . let's say i want to return " Hello " in res.json of /api/availability . it will show the old response and not " Hello "

Comment: Then you’re not running the code you think you are or it’s being cached.

Comment: i will try to clean the cache and let you know

Comment: I cleared the cache and the problem remains

Comment: If you make a code change and the behavior doesn’t change then you’re not running the code you think you are—add logging and diagnose. I’d still fix the other problems, though; this code makes little sense as-is.

Comment: lol i was running the wrong project and editing another , they do have the same name

Comment:  We've all been there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the wrong project and editing another , they do have the same name.